# Groovy - Replace ${} within a string

Tags: groovy, replace, escaping

I receive a string like this: "The code is ${code}. Your currency is ${currency}".
The ${...} characters are already part of the string, not variables.

I have a map with key-value and I would like to replace all the occurrences of the ${key} with the value:

```
def myMap = [
    'code' : '123456',
    'currency' : 'CHF'
]

myMap.each{
    fieldValue.replaceAll("${$.key}", it.value)
}
```

The expected result is the following one: "The code is 123456. Your currency is CHF".

I'm stuck because I don't know how to deal with the $ {} character escapes. I can escape the $ character but not {}. Any idea in order to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the outer `$` and use `it.key`: `"\\${$it.key}"`

Also you can use `each` here as it is for side-effects and `replaceAll`
does not modify the string (strings in java are immutable).  So you need
something like this:

```
def result = myMap.inject(fieldValue){ acc, kv ->
    acc.replaceAll("\\${$kv.key}", kv.value)
}
```

Or by using a regexp:

```
fieldValue.replaceAll(/\$\{(.+?)\}/, { _, k -> myMap[k] })
```

Answer (score 0):

It works also with closure and with delegate strategy. You can evaluate your string in the context of the map. See this example:

```
def myMap = [
    'code' : '123456',
    'currency' : 'CHF'
]

closure =  { "The code is ${code}. Your currency is ${currency}" }
closure.delegate = myMap
println closure()
```